# Prevent curtailing of socket message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

```
function parseMessage (buff){
    let obs = [];

    let done = false;
    let offset = 0;
    let size_bytes = 4;
    while(!done){
        let message_size = buff.readUIntBE(offset, size_bytes);
        let message = buff.slice(size_bytes + offset, size_bytes + offset + message_size).toString('utf8');
        offset = size_bytes+offset+message_size;
        try {
            let o = JSON.parse(message.toString());
            if (o && typeof o === "object") {
                obs.push(o);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {winston.error(e);winston.error(message);}
        if(offset >= buff.length - 1){
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return obs;
};
client_socket.on('data', function (data) {console.log(parseMessage(data));});
```

I'm using sockets to pass stringified JSON from a client to a server. The stringified JSON is prepended with 4 bytes to describe the size of the message. I'm running into a bug where after a few messages, the JSON is unable to be parse because the message string is curtailed (I think it is being sent within the next 'data' event). My question is that since its going over tcp sockets can the message be curtailed the same as it can be over extended (why I had to prepend the message with its size). If so does anyone have any elegant solutions to solve this?

The client is written in perl. I can supply the code for that if needed but I think that portion is correct.

Side question: Since the prepended message size is 4 bytes. Does that mean that my messages can have at most (2^(4'bytes' * 8'bits/byte'))/8'bits/char' = 536,870,912 characters or is that calculation incorrect?

Comment: prepending the messages with length seams over complicated to me. You can simply use new lines and the end of each. so with https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndjson it would just be `client_socket.pipe(ndjson.parse()).on('data', obj => console.log(obj));`

Comment: The problem is that some of the json contains text with newlines in it. I've thought about delimiting with some random seldom used utf8 character but that does't seem like a good idea because it will break the server if it ever encounters text that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I eventually came up with

```
function tryParseJSON(message,fail_cb){
    try {
        let o = JSON.parse(message.toString());
        if (o && typeof o === "object") {
            return(o);
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        fail_cb(err);

    }   
}

function parseMessage (active_message_buffer_size,active_message_buffer,buff){
    let obs = [];

    let done = false;
    let offset = 0;
    let size_bytes = 4;
    while(!done){

        if(!active_message_buffer.length){
            active_message_buffer_size = buff.readUIntBE(offset, size_bytes);
        }

        active_message_buffer = Buffer.concat([active_message_buffer,buff.slice(size_bytes + offset, size_bytes + offset + active_message_buffer_size)])

        if(active_message_buffer.length && (active_message_buffer.length === active_message_buffer_size)){

            let message = active_message_buffer.toString('utf8');

            let parsed_json = tryParseJSON(message,function(err){
                winston.error(err);
            });
            if(parsed_json){
                obs.push(parsed_json);
            }

            active_message_buffer = new Buffer(0);
        }

        offset = size_bytes+offset+active_message_buffer_size-1;

        if(offset >= (buff.length - 1)){
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return obs;
};

net.createServer(
    function(client_socket){
        let active_message_buffer = new Buffer(0);
        let active_message_buffer_size = null;
        client_socket.on('data',function(data){console.log(parseMessage(active_message_buffer_size,active_message_buffer,data)});
    }

);
```

It's not perfect since it doesn't account for the possibility that the first 4 bytes can be split.